# R: subsetting data based on whether a condition is met by a specific number of columns

Tags: r, bioinformatics

I have a dataframe of log2(expression-values) of genes having dimension:

```
>dim(vst.df)
34215 rows and 64 cols
```

The 64 columns refer to **22 controls** and **42 cases**. Rows refer to 34215 genes.

The dataframe looks like this:

```
>head(vst.df)[,1:5]
                        sam1      sam2      sam3      sam4      sam5
 ENSG00000000003.10 8.246215  8.671092  8.529269  8.621316  8.415544
 ENSG00000000005.5  5.187977  6.323024  6.022986  5.376513  4.810042
 ENSG00000000419.8  9.654394 10.130017 10.495403 10.209688 10.137285
 ENSG00000000457.9  8.637566  8.604159  8.681583  8.668491  8.874946
 ENSG00000000460.12 7.071433  7.302448  7.499133  7.441582  7.439453
 ENSG00000000938.8  8.713285  8.584996  8.982816  9.787420  8.823927
```

The colnames are sampleNames (from sam1...sam64) and rownames are geneIDs. Which sampleNames are cases and which are controls, is given by:

```
 >head(pData)
 sample_name status  
        sam1   case   
        sam2 contrl  
        sam3 contrl    
        sam4   case  
        sam5   case
```

The minimum value in the datframe vst is:

```
 >min(vst.df)
 4.10438
```

I need to filter the dataframe vst.df such that ***EITHER* 80% or more of all controls have values >4.10438 *OR* 80% or more of all cases have values >4.10438, per gene**.

My approach:

```
#separate the controls and cases in different dataframes
vst.controls <- vst.df[,which(colnames(vst.df) %in% as.character(pData[which(pData$status=="contrl"),1]))]
vst.cases    <- vst.df[,which(colnames(vst.df) %in% as.character(pData[which(pData$status=="case"),1]))]

#80% of controls is approx. 18
#if 80% or more controls have a value >4.10438, then the rowSums must be > round(4.10438*18)=74
vst.controls <- vst.controls[which(rowSums(vst.controls)>74),]

#similarly for cases
#80% of cases is approx. 34
#if 80% or more cases have a value >4.10438, then the rowSums must be > round(4.10438*34)=140
vst.cases <- vst.cases[which(rowSums(vst.cases)>140),]
```

Actually I know my approach is incorrect, I just wanted to show that I have tried something before posting a question here. How do I go about solving the issue?

UPDATE 1: I am showing rows from the controls' dataframe because it is smaller than cases'.

```
#row where 12 columns (<18 columns) meet the condition
vst.controls[6144,]

                    C00060  C00079   C00135  C00150   C00154  C00176  C00182   P01121  P01160  P01165   P01183   P01200   P01202  P01215   P01226   P01248   P01259
ENSG00000129824.11 4.10438 4.10438 4.903374 4.10438 5.051641 4.10438 4.10438 12.64946 4.10438 4.10438 12.14679 12.45381 12.36571 4.10438 12.05378 12.37071 12.22021
                    P01270   P01273  P01277   P01294   P01325
ENSG00000129824.11 4.10438 12.30081 4.10438 13.38687 12.07337

#row where 20 columns (>18 columns) meet the condition
vst.controls[94,]
                   C00060   C00079  C00135   C00150   C00154   C00176  C00182   P01121  P01160  P01165   P01183   P01200   P01202  P01215   P01226   P01248   P01259
ENSG00000005421.4 4.10438 5.439795 5.25585 6.207467 4.810042 5.459054 5.83844 5.573587 4.93365 4.10438 5.660449 5.075977 5.367907 4.74712 5.016934 5.350099 5.098586
                    P01270  P01273   P01277   P01294  P01325
ENSG00000005421.4 5.719316 4.80001 5.431398 5.553477 4.76463
```

UPDATE 2:

When I use this:

```
class(vst.controls)
[1] "data.frame"

class(vst.controls[1644,])
[1] "data.frame"

class(vst.controls[94,])
[1] "data.frame"

rowMeans(vst.controls[1644,] > 4.10438) #it returns me the below
ENSG00000084774.9 
                1 

rowMeans(vst.controls[94,] > 4.10438) #it returns me the below
ENSG00000005421.4 
                1
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to get how many columns have a value higher than the threshold. You can do that using `rowSums(vst.controls > 4.10438)` assuming you have no other columns except the data to be used for subsetting (i.e. `vst.controls` has exactly 22 columns). Then, the condition becomes which sum of `TRUE`s is higher that 80% of the total number of cases. For `vst.controls` that condition becomes

```
which(rowSums(vst.controls > 4.10438) > 18)    ## 80% of 22 is 17.6
```

Or even better, use `rowMeans` to have the rate of successes computed directly (regardles of the number of columns):

```
valid.controls <- which(rowMeans(vst.controls > 4.10438) > 0.8)
valid.cases <- which(rowMeans(vst.cases > 4.10438) > 0.8)
valid <- union(valid.controls, valid.cases)
```

That will give you a vector of indices that satisfy your condition.

Comment: I tried your code and it returns all 34215 rows. However, there is at least one row that I know where the condition does not meet and still it is being returned.

Comment: Can you please show two rows from your data, one that fulfills the condition, and another that doesn't?

Comment: When I run it with your data on my end, only the second case clears the condition: `rowMeans(dd > 4.10438)` returns `0.5454545`, where `dd` is the first row.

Comment: How is it possible? When I do the same thing, it returns me 
ENSG00000084774.9 
                1 for the first row and ENSG00000005421.4 
                1 for the second row

Comment: Try having it return the `rowMeans` value, not the comparison to 0.8. I get `0.545`, and it predictably returns `FALSE` on the condition.

Comment: I have added it as an update. I don't know why I cannot get the same value as you. I just don't understand.

Comment: What `class` are your entries?

Comment: they are all of the type data.frame

Comment: I tried valid.controls <- which(rowMeans(vst.controls > "4.10438") > 0.8) and it worked. I don't know why I had to put quotes around 4.10438.

Comment: That's why I asked about the class. Your data columns are character. Convert them to numbers with as.numeric() and remove the quotes from the condition.

Comment: I had actually tried that the moment you told me to check what the class of my entries is. I did rowMeans(as.numeric(vst.controls[94,]) > 4.10438) and also rowMeans(as.numeric(vst.controls[94,1:22]) > 4.10438) but it gave me an error both the times. Thanks for the help.